# Adding placeholder to text box in google custom search engine in my html website

Tags: jquery, placeholder, google-custom-search, search-box

I have added google custom search engine using following code.

```
(function() {
    var cx = '005899633628958982661:wekn1lpckzg';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
                '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

Now I have a working search box for my site, the only problem is that I am unable to use placeholder for the search-text box.

I also tried the code

```
$('input.gsc-input').attr('placeholder', 'custom text here');
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Is that input correct?  I would also use quotations `"`

Comment: are you calling this line withing document.ready? I don't see it in your code above

Comment: yes, it is uder document.ready.. i have also tried putting the code at the end of the page, but that too is not helping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688387/providing-placeholder-or-value-to-a-commercial-version-of-google-custom-search-b

Comment: i just tried the above link, do i need to make any changes in the code or should i paste it as is? because pasting it as it is, is not helping either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the following code, it worked for me!

```
(function() {   
    var cx = '!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx='+ cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();

window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').placeholder = 'SEARCH';
};
```

Comment: I guess, document.getElementsByNames('search')[0].placeholder is much better.. because id of searchbox is random.

Comment: If you are using GCS then id can be determined by inspect element. Because on complex pages there could be another element with the same name as 'search'! @AnuBhuvanendranNair document.getElementsByNames is not efficient and reliable way always.

Comment: Google custom search generates id 'gsc-i-id1' and sometimes 'gsc-i-id2'.. id value is random as of I understood. Then how document.getElementById is reliable ??

Comment: Well, It works perfectly on my live website for long time using id, so once it generates id for specific page it won't change it eventually as long as I know. You just need to find id by inspect element and you have to put it once only in the code. So For me id is SIMPLE and RELIABLE!!

Comment: id is identical on all sites that exact id is on 3 installations in my case. Thank you this solution worked well.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
window.onload = demo;

function demo() {
    document.getElementById("gsc-i-id1").setAttribute("placeholder", "SEARCH")
}
```